# Anchor tags not picking up in Chrome

Tags: tags, anchor

Workflow:
Click on PDF, click Print, Print to a Driver and when finishing the document its not picking up the anchor tags  when using Google Chrome which are \s1\ \s2\ (these have been assigned to a template for matching). However when doing the same steps in Internet Explorer it seems to work perfectly fine?

Comment: can you show your html

Comment: It's not for a HTML, I've added the anchor tags into a document as 

\s1\ for signature 1
\d1\ for date 1
\n1\ for name 1

It's then matched using a template which picks up these tags and assigns a button to each to click (click to sign, click to date etc)